# JavaScript | I require some advice with a function

Tags: javascript, html, css

How would I use JavaScript to check a style on a div which is border radius is equal to 0% or 100% then it does something.

example how would i do something like this.
this is what i think it should look like

```
if (border radius = 0%) {
starts a loader animation
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this

```
if (window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("abc")).borderRadius === "100%") {

}
```

Comment: Welcome @AnthonyL. Please accept this answer if it works for you :)

Comment: Not going to work, `border-radius` is a shortcut for four different values (border-bottom-left-radius, border-bottom-right-radius, border-top-left-radius, border-top-right-radius), it is not stored to the CSSStyleDeclaration object.

Comment: @NanditaAroraSharma didn’t quite work coming up with an error

Comment: What error are you getting?Can you please elaborate

Comment: @NanditaAroraSharma The Error is Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample to retrieve styles, compare border radius and condition:

```
// this function allows to retrieves CSS properties related to border radius
function getBordersRadius(a) {
    return {
        topLeft: window.getComputedStyle(a)['border-top-left-radius'],
        topRight: window.getComputedStyle(a)['border-top-right-radius'],
        bottomRight: window.getComputedStyle(a)['border-bottom-right-radius'],
        bottomLeft: window.getComputedStyle(a)['border-bottom-left-radius']
    }
}

// this function checks if all border radius are the same
function isAllBorderRadius(a, b) {
    var elBorderRadius = getBordersRadius(a);
    var elBorderRadiusSame = true;
    for (var i in elBorderRadius) {
        if (elBorderRadius[i] !== b) {
            elBorderRadiusSame = false;
        }
    }
    return elBorderRadiusSame;
}

// you can then use the condition
if (isAllBorderRadius(document.getElementById('ELEMENT_ID'), '100%')) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: The getBordersRadius function you created isnt working and comming up with an error.core.js:8 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'.
    at getBordersRadius

Comment: You must define a valid element in place of "document.getElementById('ELEMENT_ID')".

The element that you want to check the style must have in the sample the "id" attribute set with "ELEMENT_ID". Ex:

<div style="border-radius: 100%;" id="ELEMENT_ID">TEST</div>